# Null Reference Exception when trying to access any of the textView elements in XML

Tags: xml

I'm new to Android Studio, Kotlin and XML. Yesterday, all my code worked fine. Today, one of my scripts is broken. I've searched the web for answers but none of them fit my situation.

The Issue:
Whenever I run my app, I get a NullPointerException error, from the code

```
productTextView.append("Product: ${it.name}\nOwner: ${it.owner}\nYear Purchased: ${it.yearPurchased}\nPrice: ${it.price}\n\n")
```

All the ID's match up and it works on other parts of the app.

Heres my Kotlin code:

```
package com.example.myapplicationtutorialseries

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
       fab.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, AddProductActivity::class.java))
       }
        val preferences = getSharedPreferences("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedName = preferences.getString("savedProductName", "This Value Doesn't Exist.")
        //d("Will", "Saved message is: $savedName")
        //lastSavedProduct.text = savedName

        val products = listOf(
            Product("Google Home Mini", "Will", 2019, 69.99),
            Product("Galaxy A40", "Will", 2019, 139.50),
            Product("Monitor", "Will", 2020, 160.00),
            Product("Amazon Fire", "Will", 2019, 25.00)
        )
        var totalCost = 0.0
        products.forEach{
            productTextView.append("Product: ${it.name}\nOwner: ${it.owner}\nYear Purchased: ${it.yearPurchased}\nPrice: ${it.price}\n\n")
            totalCost += it.price
        }
        //lastSavedProduct.text = "Total Cost: $totalCost"
    }
}
```

Heres my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="defaultPosition"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of productTextView.append write productTextView.text

Comment: That won't work with my use... Like i said nothing will work with content_main.xml !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an error in my activity_main.xml file, although i have no idea how it happened!

I was missing `<include layout='@layout/content_main'/>` which meant that the textView elements were not actually getting initialised.

I have 2 XML files, the activity_main.xml and the content_main.xml. Only the first is initialised from the Kotlin script, so without the `<include layout='@layout/content_main'` the actual content of my app would not be loaded

I can't believe that i missed this... But you don't learn without mistakes! I hope this might help anyone else who somehow can get themselves into the same situation as this...